# Blank(black) screen in pygame window

Tags: python, graphics, pygame

I am running the following code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

img = pygame.image.load("Picture.jpg")

white = (255, 255, 255)

w = 900

h = 450

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))

screen.fill((white))


screen.fill((white))

screen.blit(img(0,0))

pygame.display.flip()

while True:

         for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

                     pygame.quit()
```

When I run the code the pygame window opens, but it is blank(black) screen. I also get the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/Draco/OneDrive/Documents/Programming/graphics.py", line 13, in 
    screen.blit(img(0,0))
TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable

The image I am trying to open is saved as a JPG file. The image is saved under the name Picture. Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You probably meant to write `screen.blit(img, (0,0))` instead of `screen.blit(img(0,0))`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Christian Dean has already answered it. the syntax for pygame.blit() is:

```
pygame.Surface.blit(source, dest, area=None, special_flags = 0)
```

where **source** is a image, **dest** is the coordinates of the upper left corner of place where the Surface is going to be drawn (or a Rect) and **area** is a portion of the the Surface you want to draw.

The error you made is that you tried to pass the **dest** to the image by treating it as a function.

you have to write `screen.blit(img, (0, 0))` instead. I recommend you to search the syntax in the pygame website before asking questions.

Comment: Yes, it is a typo. Please flag the question as a "simple typographical error" instead of answering and explaining his typo.

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't give me the option. I may not have the privilege of flagging yet.